# Is there a name for this website condition?

Tags: connection

[image]

Sure the website is up, but it isn't like it used to be. Diagnosis?

Comment: It could be cached?

Comment: This happens when your connection is preventing some of the mixed content (secure/insecure content).  I suggest using a VPN to solve the problem

Comment: well, the CSS and images on the page did not load. that might be due to issues in your browser, or issues on their server.

Comment: @FrankThomas not the server the website is well know to me and it works.  Learned about that company in business school

Comment: reboot your computer. Seriously, that's the first thing you should do, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the same result, the page loads perfect on both mobile and Chrome desktop for me. I would check your browser settings. Clear the cache and refresh. You can also try a different browser and see if you get the same results.